# Enable 3rd Party Module Integration on your ASP.net Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, module

I would like to learn about how to allow third party code integration (module development) with standard ASP.net WebForms Application as well MVC applications.

What should be taken care of when developing an ASP.net Web Application to be able to integrate custom modules?

What are the standard practices and general approach for this?

**Edit:**

By custom modules, it could mean something like components in Joomla CMS.

Comment: Would you please go into detail on what you mean by "custom modules" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too generic to provide a meaningful reply, but modules in most cases are encapsulated in an external class, which is referenced and registered in the web application.

If you want to be able to include new modules at runtime, you can take a look at [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) and use that. Otherwise, it would be just mostly designing your application so that it can instantiate classes from external assemblies.